# Is it a good way for getting alphabet in my project?

Tags: javascript

I did this for getting the alphabet. Is is a fast and good way to do ?

```js
function alphabet ( ) {
    const alphabet = []
    for(let i=97; i<123; i++) {
        alphabet.push(String.fromCharCode(i))
    }
    return alphabet
}

console.log(alphabet())
```

How would you write it if you had to ?

Comment: `Array.from("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")`? In your implementation, you should be avoiding `97` and `123` being "magic numbers", e.g. using `'a'.charCodeAt(0)`.

Comment: Yeah you right..

Comment: Why not just...hardcode it: `["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]`?

Comment: hardcoding is probably faster since it avoids the implicit loop over the string. with moden machines you won't notice any difference though.

Comment: @M47 yes, no difference in performance. It's *extremely* easy to read, however. It takes no time at all for a programmer to understand what this code is about. And that's usually the biggest time sink - developer time.

Comment: @VLAZ it's not that unreadable with Array.from either, especially if you use meaningful variable names but I'd go with hardcoded since it's a bit better in both aspects.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using this way, you can also split a string and get it. Two ways here:

- `String.split()`
- `Array.from()`

```js
const abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
console.log(abc.split(""));
console.log(Array.from(abc));
```

Both works.

Comment: This seems to be better approach.